# Does Angular2 have jQuery built in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Angular1 has jQuery lite built in but I am not sure about Angular2.

Does anyone know if Angular2 has jQuery built in or do I need to bring it in myself?

If it is built in, which version, jQuery lite or the full version?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install jquery via typings

```
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

Then you can declare `$` like below

```
declare var $:JQueryStatic;
```

Follow This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nq9LnK?p=preview) for example

**index.html**

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i thought typings install only installs the jquery definitions not the actual library

Comment: @danday74 you should import jquery library, have updated answer.